# Assign Latitude and Longitude values to pixels

Tags: c, geocoding, latitude-longitude

This is a problem that I have been trying to solve for some time. I have a binary file, that, after processing, leaves me with a binary bmp file, i.e, the pixels have only two values. Now, I have with me the following HDR file:

```
ENVI
description = {
PolSARpro File Imported to ENVI}
samples = 2618
lines   = 2757
bands   = 1
header offset = 0
file type = ENVI Standard
data type = 4
interleave = bsq
byte order = 0
map info = {UTM, 1, 1, 399711.555, 2641320.529, 12.500, 12.500, 45, North, WGS-84}
wavelength units = meters
band names = {
SPF_L1.bin }
```

generated by ENVI and PolSARPro. The problem I am facing is that  softwares like ENVI calculate the latitude &  longitude values for each pixel, while I am not able to find any method for replicating the same in my program ( I am using C, using PolSARPro's source files as base ). If any one could help me by explaining how to assign the positional information, it would be highly appreciated!

P.S: From my point of view, map info - `lists geographic coordinates information in the order of projection name (UTM), reference pixel x location in file coordinates, pixel y, x pixel size, y pixel size, Projection Zone, North or South for UTM only.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all of the information is there to do what you want.

You have a pixel size (meters, I presume) and a reference.  Getting the coordinates of a particular pixel involves offsetting the reference coordinates by the appropriate amount (12.5 meters times the number of pixels).  Looks like it's the same for both directions.

The `399711.555` and `2641320.529` are Easting and Northing coordinates in UTM.  (Near Steel City in India?)

You'll need another conversion to get to Lat/Long, though.

Comment: Yes, the data is about the Steel City :) So I'll need to offset the grid size (12.5) to the easting and Northing coordinates, and then convert them to Lat/Lon?

Comment: I believe so.  I'd check a few points that you know the coordinates for to verify.  (Maybe some other cities.)